# Converting from PST/PDT (Facebook timestamp) to UTC

Tags: python, facebook, datetime, timezone

Facebook API (using FQL) gives me timestamps based on Pacific timezone. It represents the number of second since 1st January 1970.
I am located in France and France time is GMT+2 in summer and GMT+1 in winter. This "summer time change" is well handled by all datetime / time functions based on local.

As you have already figured out I try to convert Facebook returned timestamp to France time. Today I discovered that Facebook returns 1310788800 for my Friday, 15th July 21:00 (French time displayed on Facebook website).
Facebook details that their timezone are PST (GMT-8h). 1310788800 is Friday, 15th July 20:00 in UTC, which leads to 22:00 in France.

So their is a 1 extra hour which leads me to these conclusions :

- Or facebook is not based on PST but PDT (taking into account a summer
  time magick change for all their dates - it seems not realistic)
- Or French summer-time change isn't taken into account in Facebook
  website and DB
- Both implies that Facebook API is very hard to use for people far
  from their servers and Facebook time management was coded with feet

No matter, the problem is the same. I want to be able to convert this date during winter and summer. To do so I have to consider this time as based on PDT and turn it into UTC time.

Do you have hint to change PDT to UTC using python ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: "(taking into account a summer time magick change for all their dates - it seems not realistic)"  apparently you share the opinion of daylight savings that most developers have...

Comment: What is the right point of view regarding daylight or universal time savings ?

Comment: The "right point of view" is that an API intended for a gloabl audience should never use local time, but rather UTC. But don't get me started about facebook not playing nicely with others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to use [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/)

```
from datetime import *
from pytz import timezone
import pytz

[...]

if (not isinstance(pacificTime, int)):
    pacificTime = int(pacificTime)
originalTimeZone = "America/Los_Angeles"
print datetime.fromtimestamp(pacificTime, pytz.timezone(originalTimeZone))
```

This solution comes from my previous post : [Changing a unix timestamp to a different timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706808/changing-a-unix-timestamp-to-a-different-timezone/6707507#6707507)

Hope it could help

Answer (score 1):

to change PDT to UTC in python, use pytz.

But the facebook API is more tricky than that, it seems. See [Facebook Events and timezones, how to convert UTC datetime to what facebook expects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134718/facebook-events-and-timezones-how-to-convert-utc-datetime-to-what-facebook-expec)

Comment: Thanks, it is solved :). My problem is just for reading event date that were created with facebook event site. I do not need to insert new events.